# How to translate a point into another plane space using Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

I am currently slicing a three-dimensional mesh using Unity but I have encountered an issue that is causing artefacts on the final result. To slice a mesh that has already previously been sliced, I need to keep track of the previous triangulated surfaces so that they can be added to their new mesh. To do this, I am simply iterating over the facet's points and determining which point is above the plane and which is below and from there I construct two different facets. However, if the plane lies between two points, then it creates a gap in the triangulated facet.

[image]

This can be seen in the above image where the blue lines represent *below* the plane, and red *above*.

I know a solution to this but I am unsure how to do it.

I already have the plane's position, which is directly where I want a new point inserted (which is directly between the two points where the gap is visible and this should add an extra triangle to close the gap) however this plane position is not on the triangulated plane.

How would I translate this point into the facet's plane?

Answer (score 0):

I had a sligtly similar issue, the result was dependent on object position. This was because meshs points are always in objects local coortinate space, and you need to convert them to/from your local space before you touch global space (i.e. take the plane position/rotation and bring it into your local space).
this is achieved using a pair of methods

```
 transform.TransformPoint(Vector3) 
 transform.InverseTransformPoint(Vector3)
```

it did require some trial and error, and may not be a solution for your problem, but is a very useful tool neverless if you are generating vertecies yourself

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and yes I have encountered issues like this but it doesn't apply to this issue unfortunately. After some research there is a method from the Vector3 class called `ProjectOnPlane`, which seems to give me what I'm after. I just need to modify it slightly.